# Why are other sell limit orders being filled before mine on exchanges like gdax?

Tags: exchanges, exchange-rate, ethereum, exchange-order

If I place a sell limit order for ETH/BTC for 4 ETH at 0.07086, when there’s currently only 0.5 ETH on it. It becomes 4.5 ETH total. Then I see it start flashing up and down, up to 10, or 20, then back down to 4.5. Multiple times. That means orders are being placed after mine that’s being sold at 0.07086 right? Why is mine not selling?

2. Another side question is, why are sell limit orders being filled at prices higher than market price? Why would people pay 0.0710 or more when there are sell orders much cheaper.

Comment: An order can disappear for two reasons: by being filled or by being cancelled.  Isn't it possible that someone placed an order for 5.5 at 0.07086 (so the size goes up to 10) and then changed their mind and cancelled their order?

Comment: For 2, that generally should not happen (barring more exotic order types like all-or-nothing).  What evidence do you have that it is happening?

Comment: Ah! It all makes sense now. Transactions all happen in batches. 1. The prices shooting up and down are from people canceling, not from sales being made. 2. I was comparing the prices in the 'history' tab to those in the 'book' tab. The prices in the history tab are sometimes higher than the prices in the book tab because the ones in book are still fluctuating. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I also wonder if the history and book tabs might be out of sync - perhaps one lags by more than the other.  So the "market price" you're seeing may not be the same market price as at the time of the trade.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the trade history on the right. Do you see any price other that the current ask and bid ? This means that orders with values other than 9000 and 8999.99 (to take the example below) are not filled, so those orders are getting canceled.

Keep in mind that this domain is heavily automated and most of the activity you see here is bots fighting each other. So this level of frequent adding/cancelling orders on the order book is quite normal.

[image]